# Quiver algebras of Dynkin type

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, gap

Let $kQ$ be one of the Dynin path algebras of type $A_n , D_n $ or $E_i$ for $i=6,7,8$.

> Question 1: How many (up to isomorphism) quiver algebras are there that are derived equivalent to $kQ$?

> Question 2: Is there an algorithm to obtain all such algebras for a given $Q$ in a quick way? Can all such algebras be obtained via QPA for a given (small) Q?

Such algebras can be obtained by taking iterated tilted algebras but there might be several different tilting modules that lead to the same algebra.

> Question 3: Define a graph with point the algebras derived equivalent to $kQ$ and edges between two different points in case they are tilted algebras of eachohter. What is this graph for a given $Q$? Does it appear in some other context?